# Issues cloning element with jQuery clone

Tags: html, jquery, dom, iframe, jquery-animate

I am attempting to create an animation using jQuery but I am having an issue, the animation is broken down into cloning a div and placing in the DOM, changing the divs ID, animating the original div and then deleting the div this all works fine but I then assign the cloned element the original divs ID(since this is used for repeating the animation) and the cloned element moves to where the deleted element was.
Is this how IDs are supposed to work.

I have tried using .remove() on the original element and I tried assigning the original element to a variable and the using .remove() on that and I have tried changing its id then deleting that id none of these have worked.

```
//animation is here
            $("#SecondPage").css("transform-origin", "center left");
            $("#Corner").css({
                "display" : "none",
                "visibility" : "hidden"
            })

            //making the page to go underneath
            $("#SecondPage").css("z-index","3");
            let NewPage = $("#SecondPage").clone(true, true);
            $(NewPage).attr("id", "NewSecondPage");
            $(NewPage).css({
                "left" : 0,
                "top" : 0,
                "position":"absolute",
                "z-index": "1"
            })
            
            $('#SecondPageContainer').append(NewPage);
            //after delete secondpage and change new cloned page to second page

            //very important this makes sure that the rotation is centered around the left side of the page rather than its center making the page rotation effect
            $({
                deg: 0
            }).animate({
                deg: 180
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                step: function (now) {
                    // in the step-callback (that is fired each step of the animation),
                    // you can use the `now` paramter which contains the current
                    // animation-position (`0` up to `angle`)
                    $('#SecondPage').css({
                        transform: 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)'
                    });
                },
                done : function(){
                    $("#Corner").css({
                        "display" : "block",
                        "visibility" : "visible"
                    })
                }

            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#FirstPage").attr("src", FirstPage);
                $("#SecondPage").remove();
                $("#NewSecondPage").attr("id", "SecondPage");
                $("#SecondPage").attr("src", SecondPage);
                //this will be called when the image is rotated
            }, 2000);
```

Comment: `$("SecondPage" + 1)` looks like a typo, otherwise, i have no idea what the actual problem here is. You can change the id of an element.

Comment: Apologies ignore that i was modifying the code thats not the cause, are you aware of the cause?

Comment: that's just it, the cause of what? it seems like while explaining what you have, you forgot to explain what it isn't doing

Comment: thats a typo when i copied the code over the issue is that i modify #SecondPage and then delete it and then rename #NewSecondPage to #SecondPage the element jumps to where the deleted #SecondPage was.

Comment: Right, because the "new" element didn't get modified when you modified the old one. CSS transforms when applied using .css apply to the element, not the selector.

Comment: yes thats what i want but the actual effect is that when i modify the original element and then delete it and then rename the new element to the old one the new element jumps to where the old element was before it was deleted.

Comment: I see, you're seeing a race condition. Don't rely on setTimeout, move all that stuff into the callback.

Comment: Ok ill try that thanks.

Comment: Thanks that worked.